# How can I fix 'Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED' error while using payu-non-seam-less-react package on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, payumoney, payu

I am using package  payu-non-seam-less-react, after installing this package my build is failing, this is my logs

**

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
115 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 107 up-to-date
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\RankBoost\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:30:7-38 Error:
Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme) from AndroidManifest.xml:30:7-38
is also present at [in.payu:payu-checkout-pro-ui:1.9.14] AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-44 value=(@style/OnePayuTheme).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-9:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing C:\Users\hp\Desktop\RankBoost\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml]
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
  .**

This is my manifest file

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  package="com.rankboost.live" >`

`

```
<application
  tools:replace="android:theme"
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  >

  
  <service
     android:name="app.notifee.core.ForegroundService"
     android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection|camera|microphone" />
   
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true"
    android:showWhenLocked="true"
    android:turnScreenOn="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

`